# button created into a Place Holder OnClientClick not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-web-developer-2010, contentplaceholder

Hi i am trying to create a Update button for my web page for a control array creasted information, it adds in the CmdUpdate button in fine, however when i click the button nothing happens.

```
'code to add in Update form
 CmdUpdate.Text = "Update"
    CmdUpdate.OnClientClick = "CmdUpdate_click()"
    CmdUpdate.ID = "CmdUpdate"
 PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(CmdUpdate)

'Sub that should be called by the CmdUpdate
Private Sub CmdUpdate_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    lblPatient.Text = Globalvar.TitleNames(5)
    lblPatientName.Text = Globalvar.TitleNames(6)
    Call SQLSuff()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be assigning a server side handler instead of a client one:

```
AddHandler CmdUpdate.Click, AddressOf CmdUpdate_click
```

Comment: @WillPeckham, you want to handle it on a client (javascript) or server (codebehind) side?

Comment: on the codebehind (label is created within a PlaceHolder1) and is one of many in an array

Comment: @WillPeckham, actually [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx) control does not have an event `TextChanged`. Maybe you are talking about [TextBox.TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx)?

Comment: yes... it seems i have been trying withe wrong control *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

Change client side click event `CmdUpdate.OnClientClick = "CmdUpdate_click()"`
to server side Onclick event.

```
CmdUpdate.OnClick = "CmdUpdate_click()
```

It will work.

Comment: I get the error 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.Protected Overridable Sub OnClick(e As System.EventArgs)' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Protected'.

Comment: change Private Sub CmdUpdate_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) access specifier Private to Protected like:Protected Sub CmdUpdate_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

Comment: The error is with the CmdUpdate.onclick it don't like the .Onclick